# Using CSS hover class to hover over a link and display an overlay image elsewhere on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to figure out if there was a way to use CSS to hover over a link and make an overlay of an image show elsewhere on the page. I am making a website that has a map, and what I want to accomplish is that when they hover over a link to the corresponding location the map would sort of highlight the location of what it is they are hovering over to get a better understanding of where the place is and not have to search for it. What I am getting now is that I have to hover over the location on the image and then I get the effect but I want the effect when I hover over the link.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

I apologize for the lack of code you guys.

Here are the divs that I am using to create some simple overlays. Just some color blocks.

```
<div class="roomOverlay blue" id="conf_sanchez"></div>
    <div class="roomOverlay red" id="conf_CIO"></div>
    <div class="roomOverlay green" id="conf_10F"></div>
    <div class="roomOverlay brown" id="Fuster"></div>
```

and here is the css

```
.blue:hover { background-color: Blue; }
.red:hover { background-color: red; }
.green:hover { background-color: green; }
.brown:hover { background-color: brown; }

#conf_sanchez {
height: 104px;
width: 96px;
left: 876px;
top: 14px;}

#conf_CIO {
height: 146px;
width: 69px;
left: 7px;
top: -92px;}

#conf_10F {
height: 67px;
width: 115px;
left: 194px;
top: 193px;}

#Fuster {
height: 139px;
width: 129px;
left: 180px;
top: -17px;}
```

**FIXED** What I had to do was a script since it became difficult positioning with the HTML and CSS. I used the data-overlay tag in my HTML as so.

```
 <dl> <dt><a href="#" **data-overlay="#Fuster"**>Fuster Conference Room - W Side behind small break room</a></dt>
        <dd>-Projector</dd>
        <dd>-Computer</dd>
        <dd>-Polycom</dd>
        <dd>-Seats 8-10 people</dd>
        <dd>-4 White Boards</dd>
    </dl>
```

**JQuery Script:**

```
  $(function () {
    $('.roomOverlay').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('a').hover(function () {
        var overlay = $(this).data("overlay");
        $(overlay).css("visibility", "visible");
    }, function () {
        var overlay = $(this).data("overlay");
        $(overlay).css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
});
```

Here is the [page showing the result](http://cdpn.io/DbAvF) for it. It does not show image for security purposes but the effect works on the empty image. :)

Comment: `$('a').hover(function(){$('whateverID').show();});`, or you could fade it in. Hard to help without code.

Comment: SO is for people to help you with your code.  We can make suggestions, however, your should always try to provide some code or ideas you have tried first

Comment: please provide the code you have tried uptill now, without that we could not suggest anything!

Comment: You really should not being doing this with css. For it to work with css the image elsewhere must be a child of the link, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @ Fresheyeball child or adjacent (even nested in adjacent tag) to link you mean  i believe:)

Comment: Can anyone tell me why my answer (which seems to be used in the end) is with -2 at the bottom???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you specified using css for this problem, but using JS(jQuery) will make the answer more flexible for larger projects.

**HTML**

```
<img class="image" src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/00/1d/3d/32/new-york-city.jpg">
<img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCk4R8uFRe5EnqH9KrV3u-K1VcCp3y_qSG8vezNG5uSX7G-FMHvQ">
<img class="image" src="http://images1.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/New-York-City-new-york-1020054_1024_768.jpg">
<img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSF_1ueOgxtgkT8HFuwO3f3K5fEtUxJtC-IICVWYcXJkchmgT1c">
<div class="links">
<a href="#" title="Example link!">Option 1</a> 
<a href="#" title="Example link!">Option 2</a> 
<a href="#" title="Example link!">Option 3</a> 
<a href="#" title="Example link!">Option 4</a> 
</div>
```

This sets up a templete for us to display the images specified.  When the user hovers over a link, the corresponding image will display.

**CSS**

```
img.image {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
}
img.active {
  display: block;
}
.links {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This just sets some basic positioning.  The `.active` is the class that will be applied to the current image.  It will change the display from `none` to `block`.
**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('a').hover(function() {
    var item = $('a').index(this);
    $('.image').removeClass('active');
    $('.image').eq(item).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

This is where the magic happens.  When the user hovers over a link, jQuery determines which link is hovered by taking its [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/).  Then jQuery takes that index and finds an image with the same index and adds the class `.active` to it.  Therefore, no matter how large a project is and how many links and images you have, it is scalable to whichever size project.
The same concept is used by slideshows.

Here is an example of this in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nCDhG

Comment: Yes, I believe jQuery would be a better solution for this problem but was wondering if it could be done just with strict HTML and CSS since the overlays will have a fixed position on the map. Like hide overlay, hover over link, display overlay.

Comment: Ok.  However that is alot of repeated CSS to associate each link with an image.

Comment: While using the index() function what if you have the situation where your link is inside a <dl></dl> tag? Will it still find the <a></a> tag within there? Example: 'code' <dl> <a href="#"><dt>Description</dt></a> 'code'

Comment: in that situation change the index of the `a` tag to `dl` tag.  Same if it were in a list.  You would get the index of `li`

Answer (score 1):

For a CSS-only solution, you may want to look into [child selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).

This will allow you to hover over the parent and show the child.

For instance

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent { properties }
#child {properties; height: 0}
#parent:hover > #child { height: 200px; properties}
```

Idea based off of provided code: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/nDyWF/1/

As others have mentioned,  you may be better suited with a JS/Jquery solution.  This is a bit dirty, but it is possible.

Comment: "an image show elsewhere on the page" Doing that with pure CSS will require some odd positioning...

Comment: With css  , respecting cascade and using right selector, it might be possible. But, the op provided no code ...

Comment: Sounds like he may need a fixed position regardless, so odd positioning may work. Who knows without that darned code!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/nDyWF/1/  I am not sure exactly what you need from your code, but here is an idea based off of it.

Comment: I did but it got a little messy with the positioning so I went with a JS solution as I updated the post! Thanks though! Neat implementation!

Answer (score 0):

You could do some stuff with positioning. Let's break out the ASCII art:

```
<div>
------------------------------------------------------
|                             |    <img class="map"> |
|  <a>This is link            |                      |
|     <span>Overlay</span>    |                      |
|  </a>                       |                      |
|                             |                      |
|  <a>This is another link    |                      |
|     <span>Overlay</span>    |                      |
|  </a>                       |                      |
|                             |                      |
------------------------------------------------------
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

div img,
div a span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

div img {
    z-index: 5;
}

a span {
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
}

a:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

I don't think `a:hover span` will work in IE 6, but it should do in other browsers.

Answer (score -2):

Use JQuery:

```
$("#link1").hover(
  function () {
    $('#map1').show();
  },
  function () {
    $('#map1').hide();
  }
);
```

The first is mouse-in the second function is mouse-out.

Comment: Let me try something like this out see what I come up with. Thanks!